# Convert a questionnaire to an object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, recursion

hope you can help me, I did figure out some recursions before but it's not one of the days. I have such array as a result of a questionnaire:

```
Array
(
    [Q1] => Array
        (
            [A3] => Array
                (
                    [Q11] => Array
                        (
                            [A11] => Array
                                (
                                    [Q111] => A112
                                )
                        )
                    [Q12] => Array
                        (
                            [A23] => Stackoverflow
                        )
                )
        )
    [Q2] => A5
)
```

These are questions and answers (I cannot rely on their index or prefix, but they always come as pair) and if an answer is array, it has subquestions. Q1 has A3 as answer, and it has A11 as nested answer to Q11, and finally A112 as the final answer to Q111 in that branch. But Q1 also has a a paralel subquestion, A23 was selected and as it was "Other:" option, the user entered text. Finally, A5 answers was selected for second question.

For faster entry, this is the array in JSON:

```
    {"Q1":{"A3":{"Q11":{"A11":{"Q111":"A112"}},"Q12":{"A23":"Stackoverflow"}}},"Q2":"A5"}
```

So now, I need to get the result in such object:

```
{
    "questions": [{
            "questionId": "Q1",
            "answers": [{
                "answerId": "A3",
                "questions": [{
                        "questionId": "Q11",
                        "answers": [{
                            "answerId": "A11",
                            "questions": [{
                                "questionId": "Q111",
                                "answers": [{
                                    "answerId": "A112"
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "questionId": "Q12",
                        "answers": [{
                            "answerId": "A23",
                            "answerPhrase": "Stackoverflow"
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "questionId": "Q2",
            "answers": [{
                "answerId": "A5"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm sure it's relatively simple with recursion but after trying and getting lost, I tried JSON and that was even worse. I remind you that the Q and A's come in pairs, so I believe the recursion should have two nested loops but you may know better - I just cannot rely on the index values. Thanks in advance, PHP wizards!

[image: screenshot of the form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this gives you what you need. It is done using recursive functions. The only thing different from my result and the result you are looking for is that Q1 and Q2 are on the same level and not as another object under answers. Based on the rest of your question I have presumed that is a typo and what I have done will be correct.

```
$response = json_decode('{"Q1":{"A3":{"Q11":{"A11":{"Q111":"A112"}},"Q12":{"A23":"Stackoverflow"}}},"Q2":"A5"}', true);

function processQuestions($questions)
{
  $ret = array();
  if(!empty($questions))
  {
    foreach($questions as $question => $answer)
    {
      $ret[] = array(
          'questionId' => $question,
          'answers' => processAnswers($answer),
      );
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}

function processAnswers($answers)
{
  if(!is_array($answers))
  {
    return array(array('answerId'=>$answers));
  }

  $ret = array();
  if(!empty($answers))
  {
    foreach($answers as $answerId=>$answer)
    {
      $ans = array('answerId'=>$answerId);
      if(is_array($answer))
      {
        $ans['questions'] = processQuestions($answer);
      }
      else
      {
        $ans['answerPhrase'] = $answer;
      }
      $ret[] = $ans;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}

$result = array('questions'=>processQuestions($response));
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, that's almost perfect! Very elegant approach with two functions calling each other. It's only now that the answers are arrays of objects - even if it's only answerId there.

Comment: I have edited the code, is that right now? Changed one line in processAnswers, line 24.

Comment: It is perfect. Thank you! And yes, the resulting JSON was wrong, fixed now.